# Partition a vector into equally sized groups

Tags: r, optimization, partitioning

I have a vector of positive numbers `x` in R and I want to find a way to partition it into `k` groups so that all the groups have approximately the same sum.

The groups must be contiguous (wrt to the indices), i.e. the `grouping` vector which gives a group number for each element must be monotonically increasing (and have only `k` unique values).

I don't care too much about the specific metric being optimized, as long as it seems to reasonably fit the requirement that "all groups have approximately the same sum". This is for a very practical application, not academic or anything. I'm more just curious if this comes up in some other context where there is already a widely used method for doing something like this.

But, to get the question started I'll suggest an example optimization metric. Minimize the sum of squared differences between each group sum and `sum(x)/k`. You can see that `grouping` below is not a very good grouping. Some groups have means much higher and others much lower than `sum(x)/k`.

```r
set.seed(2021)
n <- 20
x <- runif(n) * (-seq(n)^(3.5/10) + 3)
dput(x)
#> c(0.902534733526409, 1.3523645022211, 1.0865939625239, 0.525087398394772, 
#> 0.791290875074404, 0.790975940076622, 0.655817101893165, 0.247870845831615, 
#> 0.686854609626634, 0.748327123592228, 0.01868717588849, 0.514021263397077, 
#> 0.3293502987338, 0.273219395008493, 0.34436257707878, 0.0908132509751022, 
#> 0.153867128249851, 0.216814852961724, 0.189128701757822, 0.0800070215205274
#> )

k <- 5

grouping <- seq_along(x) %/% k
grp_sums <- tapply(x, grouping, sum)
error <- sum((sum(x)/k - grp_sums)^2)
error
#> [1] 9.569577
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Here's some example partitioning functions with their error distributions. Somehow seems like there must be some commonly used function out there to do a little better somehow, but maybe not. The `p2` function is the method suggested by @whuber in the comments.

```r
p1 <- function(x, k) {
  g <- cut(cumsum(x), c(-Inf, seq(1, k - 1) * sum(x) / k, Inf))
  grouping <- as.integer(g)
}
p2 <- function(x, k) {
  f <- approxfun(c(0, cumsum(x) / sum(x)), c(0, seq_along(x)))
  i <- f(seq(0, 1, length.out = k + 1))
  j <- rep(0, length(x))
  j[round(1 + i[-length(i)])] <- 1
  grouping <- cumsum(j)
}

x <- replicate(100, runif(20), simplify = FALSE)

error1 <- sapply(x, function(x) {
  k <- 5
  grp_sums <- tapply(x, p1(x, k), sum)
  error <- sum((sum(x) / k - grp_sums)^2)
  error
})

error2 <- sapply(x, function(x) {
  k <- 5
  grp_sums <- tapply(x, p2(x, k), sum)
  error <- sum((sum(x) / k - grp_sums)^2)
  error
})

quantile(error1)
#>         0%        25%        50%        75%       100% 
#> 0.06458521 0.32530262 0.60081350 0.95325869 3.13349956
quantile(error2)
#>          0%         25%         50%         75%        100% 
#> 0.005463701 0.162419464 0.272996620 0.435938237 1.200632183
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Start with a better heuristic.  For instance, `f <- approxfun(c(0, cumsum(x)/sum(x)), c(0, seq_along(x)));
i <- f(seq(0, 1, length.out=k+1));
j <- rep(0, length(x));
j[round(1+i[-length(i)])] <- 1;
grouping <- cumsum(j)` gives an initial error of just 0.398.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, that's a pretty good starting point, I'll start with that and look for ways to modify if no other suggestions